# Adding removed tabs in QTabWidget (PyQT)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtabwidget

I'm facing an issue with pyQT.
So I created a graphical interface with designer, containing a QTabWidget.
The things is I would like to hide and show tabs when my function is running. I found one solution that consists in removing all the tabs and adding them later.
Lets say I only have two tabs :

```
removedTab = self._application.getAlgorithmGUI().getWidget('tabWidget_Verification').widget(1)
self._application.getAlgorithmGUI().getWidget( 'tabWidget_Verification' ).removeTab( 1 )
```

And when I try later to add this removed tab, my program crashes.

```
self._application.getAlgorithmGUI().getWidget( 'tabWidget_Verification' ).addTab(removedTab,QString.fromUtf8("TabRemoved"))
```

This is my error message :

```
QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents: Cannot send posted events for objects in another thread
QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents: Cannot send posted events for objects in another thread
QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents: Cannot send posted events for objects in another thread
QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents: Cannot send posted events for objects in another thread
<unknown>: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.0.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually it is not clear enough. Why are you "removing all the tabs and adding them later"? Why don't you declare all the tabs you need and call them when you want and remove them from index when don't want them anymore?

Comment: In the first place I just wanted to hide some tabs and show them at a precise moment of my function. As there is no hide/show methods for tabs, I found that solution that removes the tabs I created in my .ui (without deleting them).

Answer (score 2):

You can declare all the tabs you need in your mainwindow object or whatever widget you have:
Ex.:

```
self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
```

And you can assign the widgets to your tabs normally even if you didn't call the `addTab()` method yet.
Ex.:

```
self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.tab)
```

Whenever it is necessary, you can show your tab.
Ex.:

```
self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "Label")
```

And on the same way, you can also remove it again, from its index number.
Ex.:

```
self.tabWidget.removeTab(3)
```

The same tab can be called again as many times as you want.
I think this way is quite clean and simple.
If this doesn't fit in your needs please let me know.

Comment: Well the things is I have to build my widget separately in a .ui file. So that's why I need to create all my tabs before I run my function.

Anyway, I tried your solution, but I get this message :

Comment: QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents: Cannot send posted events for objects in another thread
    QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents: Cannot send posted events for objects in another thread
    QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents: Cannot send posted events for objects in another thread
    QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
    QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents: Cannot send posted events for objects in another thread

Comment: QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents: Cannot send posted events for objects in another thread
    <unknown>: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.0.

I'm kinda lost. :/

Comment: If you keep getting these errors the problem isn't with your tabs. Are you using threads? I think you have to put more of your code up there so we can take a look. I think that possibly your problem is in the assigning of the parent widgets.

Comment: Well you are possibly right about threads, I have to ask the guy that designed the environment in which I'm coding.